# The right way to pass a database object?

Tags: php, mysqli, fatal-error, prepare

I have 2 classes:
1. Database Class

```
class Database extends Config{

private $connection;

function __construct()
{
    $this->openConn();
}

public function openConn(){
    $this->connection = new mysqli($this->dbHost . ":" . $this->dbPort,
                                       $this->dbUser,
                                       $this->dbPass,
                                       $this->dbName);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo 'Database connection failed ' . mysqli_errno() . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
}
```

2. Login Class

```
class Login{

private $connection;

function __construct(){

    global $database;
    $this->connection = $database;

    $query = $this->connection->prep("
        SELECT * FROM `Users`
        WHERE `Email` = ?
        AND `Password` = ?
        LIMIT 1
        ");
}
```

After binding params, and trying to run Login.php, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::prepare()
```

After searching online I found many ideas but no practical examples, as I understood, the mysqli object is not being passed correctly, and I should use another approach to pass it as it should (if extending the Database class can be prevented - it would be preferred, as I plan to use the "extends" option for another use).

Thank you.

Comment: Try calling prepare on the connection and not the Database class which does not contain a prepare method, as per my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your *Openconn()* is not returning anything.

Make sure your it returns the database cursor

You can do this by updating your code into:

```
public function openConn(){
    $this->connection = new mysqli($this->dbHost . ":" . 
         $this->dbPort, 
         $this->dbUser, 
         $this->dbPass, 
         $this->dbName);

    //Check for connection errors

    return $this-connection;
}
```

Comment: Why use ()? Because it is an object and not a simple variable? (I am used to see () while working with functions usually..).

Answer (score 0):

So many things where do I start, I guess I will post the corrected code first ( untested )

```
class Database extends Config{

    private $connection;

    function __construct(){
        $this->openConn();
    }

    protected function openConn(){
            $this->connection = new mysqli($this->dbHost . ":" . $this->dbPort,
                    $this->dbUser,
                    $this->dbPass,
                    $this->dbName);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                echo 'Database connection failed ' . mysqli_errno() . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
    }

    public function getConnection(){
        return $this->connection;
    }
}

class Login{
    private $Database;

    function __construct(\Database $Database){
        $this->Database = $Database;
        $connection = $this->Database->getConnection();

        $query = $connection->prep("
    SELECT * FROM `Users`
    WHERE `Email` = ?
    AND `Password` = ?
    LIMIT 1
    ");
    }
}
```

You should avoid globals and instead use dependency injection.  So this

```
 global $database
```

Is replaced with

```
$Database = new Database();
$Login = new Login( $Database  );
```

I'm not sure what that global was, if it was a Database instance or the actual connection, but the `$connetion` in the Database class is private so in order to get it outside it should have a get method.  I also changed the openConn() method to be protected because it's pointless calling from outside the class.

There are a lot of other things that I would change, or do differently but it largely outside the scope of the question.

Most likely your issue is:

- you are not setting the global
- you are setting the global to be a $Database and not the connection.

Based on the error you report it's most likely the second one, because you are calling prepare on the Database class and not it's stored connection.

Comment: global $database came mainly from: https://www.lynda.com/PHP-tutorials/php-with-OOP-beyond-the-basics/653-2.html
As I understand from you, it is not a good approach.
I'll go over your solution and update if I succeeded using it.

Thank you very much.